# (PHP) file_get_contents with a Authorization Header

Tags: php

How do I use file_get_contents to send a authorization header

I currently have file_get_contents get it with a user agent but I also would like to add a authorization header so I get a functional response instead of a 401 error

```
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$url = file_get_contents("http://websitethatneedsaauthorizationheader.com", false, $context);
```

I basically need to copy the authorization header from here:
[image: Authorization Header]

and then use that on this website and not get a 401 error
[image: 401 response from website without header]

this is what it is supposed to look like with the authorization header
[image: working response from website with header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the \n of the User-Agent header, add the autorization header, like this:

```
$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-Agent: SomeUser\r\nAuthorization: SomeKey"
  )
);
```